# How can I refer to the event object from an external function? - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble referring to the event object in a jQuery function:

```
// Execute a function when an image with the arrow class is clicked
$('.arrow').bind('click',update_support);

// Function tries to refer to the calling image using $(this)
function update_support() {
  alert( $(this).src );
}

// Result: an alert of 'undefined'
```

This code does work, but it passes the "this" object to the function explicitly, and I feel like there must be a better way:

```
$('.arrow').bind('click',update_support(this));

function update_support(obj) {
  alert( obj.src );
}

// Result: an alert with the src of the clicked image
```

**Edit to make my question clearer:**
Why should I have to give any arguments to the function explicitly? From jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object: "The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler." My question is: if I don't pass it explicitly, where is it? ;) ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.arrow').bind('click',function(event){ update_support(event);} );
```

Untested, but that should pass a reference to the event into `update_support`.

**Edit**: You'd also need to modify `update_support`, obviously:

```
function update_support(evt) {
  alert( evt.target.src );
}
```

Comment: that'll work, but it looks like the OP wants the `event.target` inside of `update_support()` function as they want to get the `src` property

Comment: +1 for the edit, although the anonymous function wrapping `update_support` is not necessary - the event object will be passed as the first argument to it, a parameter is needed in the function signature to capture the value

Comment: well, you could reference it with using `arguments` like so `arguments[0]`, but IMO it makes it slightly easier having a parameter to capture the argument value.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
alert( $(this).src );
```

Try:

```
alert( this.src );
```

`$(this)` is a jQuery object. `this` is a DOM element.

Comment: Didn't work - still returned undefined.  :( Since jQuery is calling the function, and (maybe) passing in arguments such as which object triggered the function, why wouldn't a jQuery object make sense?

Comment: @Summer - Because `src` is not a property of a jQuery object. If you really wanted to wrap `this` (which is the element on which the event is raised) in this context, then you would use `$(this).attr('src')` to get the value of the `src` property. That's a lot of unnecessary wrapping and function calls though.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to both [inkedmn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420592/how-can-i-refer-to-the-event-object-from-an-external-function-jquery/2420628#2420628)'s and [J-P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420592/how-can-i-refer-to-the-event-object-from-an-external-function-jquery/2420613#2420613)'s answers

```
// Execute a function when an image with the arrow class is clicked
$('.arrow').bind('click',update_support);

// Function tries to refer to the calling image using $(this)
function update_support(e) {
  alert( e.target.src );
}
```

`e` in this case is the `event` object (normalised across browsers)

If you don't define a parameter for the event object argument explicitly in the event handler signature, the event object can be referenced using `arguments`

```
// Execute a function when an image with the arrow class is clicked
$('.arrow').bind('click',update_support);

// Function tries to refer to the calling image using $(this)
function update_support() {
  alert( arguments[0].target.src );
}
```

But in my honest opinion, it would make the code easier to read by explicitly defining a parameter for the event object argument.

Comment: I tried this, but my browser reports that e is undefined when it's not passed explicitly.

Comment: what do you mean when you say it's not passed explicitly? do you mean removing the parameter from `update_support` function signature? In this case, `e` would be undefined as it is not defined anywhere (excluding the notion that a variable `e` may be declared in parent scope).

Comment: Agreed.  I meant when I don't use .bind('click',update_support(this)) and instead try using .bind('click',update_support) or .bind('click',update_support(event)) -- it doesn't work.  Perhaps I'll just go with what works on this one and leave prettier syntax for later.  :)

Comment: I've given you the de facto answer though!

Comment: I agree - "it would make the code easier to read by explicitly defining a parameter for the event object argument" :)  Thanks for bearing with me.